# database & web application Server specification

Tags: database, web-applications, iis-7, storage, sql-server-2012

i want to buy a hardware for an environment 
uses Sqlsever 2012 as a database server and running an ASP.net application over .net frame work 4 as an interface 
we have about 1000 user who use the we application only to read data and we have 3 databases 2 of them updated every month each of them update by a 200 MB transaction The third database updates by a 15 MB Transaction every 15 mints every week the data become useless
and only one user updates the 3 databases
i have no experience in server design or storage design but i did some research and i found this solution

Dell PowerEdge T620 Server

processor : Intel® Xeon® E5-2620 2.00GHz, 15M Cache, 7.2GT/s QPI, Turbo, 6C 95W
No additional processor 
Memory : 4 X 8GB RDIMM, 1600 MT/s, Standard Volt, Dual Rank, x4 Data Width 
Os :    Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Enterprise Edition,x64
HDD : 4 X 146GB 15K RPM SAS 6Gbps 2.5in Hot-plug Hard Drive,3.5in HYB CARR

please if i am in the wrong direction set me straight

Answer (score -1):

I guess  it doesnt matter how much you want to store but the challeng is how many user going to access you server per seconds or minute and to each limit you server will still up, so just try to seek for server with giant proccesser and sutable size of ram

Comment: This isn't a particularly detailed answer, especially considering that the OP has a specific proposed hardware config.  How would I go about acquiring a "server with giant processor"?

Comment: 32 GB of ram and xeon E5-2620 2GHz  isn't suitable enough ??
we have 100 user / minute during the day time and 20 user per minute during night time